# Custom Theme Fields in Settings Menu - apply filters to one of those fields?

Tags: custom-field, filters, options

I found an interesting concepts of adding an additional option to the "General Options" in Wordpress.

```
/**
 * Custom Theme Settings
 * see http://digwp.com/2009/09/global-custom-fields-take-two/
 */

add_action('admin_menu', 'add_gcf_interface');

function add_gcf_interface() {
    add_options_page('Other', 'Other', '8', 'functions', 'otherGlobalOptions');
}

function otherGlobalOptions() {
    ?>
    <div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Sonstiges</h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">
        <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
        <p><strong>Welcome Message</strong><br />
        <textarea name="welcomemessage" cols="100%" rows="7"><?php echo get_option('welcomemessage'); ?></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" /></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
        <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="welcomemessage" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

**This works just fine.**

I'm just wondering now if there is a chance to apply a filter to that input?

Like I can do `add_filter('the_content', 'wr_replace_text', 100);` I want to do

```
add_filter('welcomemessage', 'wr_replace_text', 100);
```

Is that somehow possible, because this doesn't work for me at the moment.

Kind regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom filter using [filter functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) of Plugin API.
I have changed you code as following to create and use custom filter.

```
function add_gcf_interface() {
add_options_page('Other', 'Other', '8', 'functions', 'otherGlobalOptions');
}

function otherGlobalOptions() {
?>
<div class='wrap'>
<h2>Sonstiges</h2>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('update-options') ?>
    <p><strong>Welcome Message</strong><br />
    <textarea name="welcomemessage" cols="100%" rows="7"><?php echo apply_filters('welcomemessage',get_option('welcomemessage')); ?></textarea></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save" /></p>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="update" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_options" value="welcomemessage" />
</form>
</div>
<?php
}
// Create custom filter
function add_welcomemessage($welcomemessage) {   
return $welcomemessage;
}
add_filter('welcomemessage', 'add_welcomemessage');
```

Tell me whether it worked for you or i will provide another solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to strongly recommend you to read these articles:

- [The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings API, Part 1: What It
  Is, Why It Matters](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-1/)
- [The Complete Guide To The WordPress Settings    API, Part 2:
  Sections, Fields, and Settings](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-2-sections-fields-and-settings/)
- [The Complete Guide    To The    WordPress Settings API, Part 3: All
  About Menus](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-3-all-about-menus/)
- [The    Complete    Guide To The WordPress Settings    API, Part 4:
  On Theme    Options](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-4-on-theme-options/)
- [The Complete Guide To The    WordPress Settings API, Part    5:
  Tabbed    Navigation For Your    Settings Page](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-5-tabbed-navigation-for-your-settings-page/)
- [The Complete Guide    To The    WordPress Settings    API, Part 6:
  Menu Pages](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-6-menu-pages/)
- [The Complete    Guide    To The    WordPress Settings API, Part 7:
  Validation,    Sanitisation,    and    Input I](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-7-validation-sanitisation-and-input-i/)
- [The Complete Guide To The WordPress    Settings API,       Part 8:
  Validation, Sanitisation, and Input II](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-the-wordpress-settings-api-part-8-validation-sanitisation-and-input-ii/)

During reading these articles, you will find <strike>an interesting</strike> proper concepts of adding an additional option to the "General Options" in WordPress and much more useful information.

Comment: Thank you, perfect! I'll give it a read. However for the direct answer to my question I accepted the answer of @Vinod Dalvi